# Matrix notation for multiple rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there an elegant way to notate multiple rows or columns of a matrix as a new matrix for math equation? For example, I want to use the rows in a matrix which ranged from i to j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be a matrix and let $m_i$ denote the vector corresponding to the $i$-th row of $M$. Then you could denote the submatrix given by rows $i$ through $j$ by 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
m_i \\
m_{i+1} \\
\vdots \\
m_j
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$

A more compact notation would be to define indexing sets $I, J$. Assume $M$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, let $M_{i,j}$ denote the $(i,j)$-th element of $M$ and let $I \subseteq \{1, \dots, m\}$ and $J \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$. Then define by $M_{IJ}$ the submatrix of $M$ corresponding to all elements of $M$ indexed by elements of $I \times J$.

Then you could write your matrix as $M_{IJ}$ using the index sets $I = \{i, i+1, \dots, j\}$ and $J = \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.